# 'choices' must be an iterable containing

Tags: django-models

I'm learning Django and I had an error in code

```
class Nomzod(models.Model):

Y = [
    ("Erkak", "Erkak"),
    ("Ayol", "Ayol"),
]

ism_f = models.CharField(max_length=100)
email = models.EmailField(unique=True, blank=True)
birinchisi = models.BooleanField(default=True)
jins = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=Y)
```

Error:

```
asosiy.Universitet.yillik: (fields.E005) 'choices' must be an iterable containing (actual value, human readable name) tuples.System check identified 1 issue (0 silenced)
```

What I must do. Please help me

I already watched guides but they didn't helped me(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making your Y as tuple of tuples like this :

```
Y = (
    ("Erkak", ("Erkak")),
    ("Ayol", ("Ayol")),
)
```

Comment: I edit my answer, please try edited version and let me know